# C# WPF Telerik RadDiagramShape Add Key Event Handlers Intermittent Failure

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, onkeydown, onkeyup

I'm adding and removing Keyboard key down and up handlers for the selected RadDiagramShape in a RadDiagram.

I have a ManipulationAdorner (a Telerik resize/move adorner construct) on the selected shape, which I use for custom drag resize (my drag resize elements are Thumbs).

The desired functionality is that holding shift constrains the aspect ratio during drag resize.

This works, most of the time.

I have a method that finds the selected shape based on the selected item (as the selected shape contains the selected item as its "Content"). I've verified this is returning the correct shape.

I've also verified that my Keyboard.AddKeyUpHandler(selectedShape, OnKeyUp) / Keyboard.AddKeyDownHandler(selectedShape, OnKeyDown) calls are always executing when desired (i.e. in the drag started event).

Sometimes, the OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp handlers are simply never called when pressing the shift key (or any key, for that matter), even though the add handler calls were just previously called.

**My question is, what could be causing this behaviour?**

I've tried to determine if focus is causing the issue, and I can't prove that focus is changing. Sometimes, I'll have to simply click off the selected shape, and click it again, to get the shift handlers properly working. The strange thing is, in both cases, the event handlers are added when drag starts.

CheckShiftDepressed() is a manual call to check if a shift key is depressed before drag resizing starts. The only reason I detect shift key changes during drag resize is to instantaneously reshape the dragged selected shape when shift is pressed and released (according to the aspect ratio, or, when released, the cursor position).

Thanks in advance,

Ryan

Revelant bits of code and XAML below:

The resizing thumbs:

```
<Style x:Key="ResizingThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">  
    ...         
    <EventSetter Event="DragStarted" Handler="ResizingThumb_DragStarted" />
    <EventSetter Event="DragDelta" Handler="ResizingThumb_DragDelta" />
    <EventSetter Event="DragCompleted" Handler="ResizingThumb_DragCompleted" />
</Style>
```

Drag resize started:

```
private void ResizingThumb_DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the dragged shape starting aspect ratio.
    if (u_rd_Diagram.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        ...
        CheckShiftDepressed();

        SetSelectedShapeShiftKeyListening(true);
    }
```

CheckShiftDepressed:

```
private void CheckShiftDepressed()
{
    m_ShiftDepressed = (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift)) ? true : false;
}
```

Drag resize completed:

```
private void ResizingThumb_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    CheckShiftDepressed();

    SetSelectedShapeShiftKeyListening(false);
}
```

Set key listening events on the selected shape:

```
private void SetSelectedShapeShiftKeyListening(bool ListenForShiftKeyChanges)
{
    RadDiagramShape selectedShape = null;

    if (GetSelectedShape(out selectedShape))
    {
        if (ListenForShiftKeyChanges)
        {
            Keyboard.AddKeyUpHandler(selectedShape, OnKeyUp);
            Keyboard.AddKeyDownHandler(selectedShape, OnKeyDown);
        }
        else
        {
            Keyboard.RemoveKeyUpHandler(selectedShape, OnKeyUp);
            Keyboard.RemoveKeyDownHandler(selectedShape, OnKeyDown);
        }
    }
}
```

For anyone's interest, the OnKeyUp and OnKeyDown handler methods:

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    CheckShiftDepressed();

    if (m_DraggingResizingThumb)
    {
        OnAspectRatioResizingToggled();
    }
}

private void OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    CheckShiftDepressed();

    if (m_DraggingResizingThumb)
    {
        OnAspectRatioResizingToggled();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this.

The telerik RadDiagram (at least in this case) can't seem to make up its mind on whether or not it or its selected shape has focus.

I'm not sure why the selected shape can appear to have focus, and be draggable, movable, etc., have its selected adorner showing, if the diagram has focus, and at other times, the selected shape has focus.

Manually calling Focus() on the selected shape after adding the key up and down handlers solved this issue for me.